# Unable to save the correct file format to S3 using Databricks (python)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, databricks

I just started using Databricks a few days ago and I am trying to grab some log files from S3/bucket_name/../raw and process it to check if the logs contains certain lines I want to work with and save the lines to another folder called 'S3/bucket_name/../processed/

This is what I have tried so far.

```
RAW_LOG_PATH = "dbfs:/mnt/" + AWS_BUCKET_NAME + RAW_FILE_PATH
PROCESSED_LOG_PATH = "dbfs:/mnt/" + AWS_BUCKET_NAME + PROCESSED_FILE_PATH

raw_file_list = dbutils.fs.ls(RAW_LOG_PATH)
processed_file_list = dbutils.fs.ls(PROCESSED_LOG_PATH)    
processed_file_names = [file.name for file in processed_file_list]

#Filter log records that contains 'country:France'and save it to my_records 
for file in raw_file_list:
  if file.name not in processed_file_names:
    my_records = []
    my_entries = sc.textFile(file.path)
    lines = my_entries.collect()
    for line in lines:
      if 'country:France' in line: 
        my_records.append(line)
    new_file = PROCESSED_LOG_PATH + file.name
    if len(mobile_recs_logs) > 0:
      dbutils.fs.put(str(new_file), str(my_records))
      print('File processed:', new_file, len(my_records))
    else:
      print ('No records:', file.name, len(my_records))
```

I am able to extract the rows I want and output a new file onto a new processed folder on S3. But, when I try to access that file and output the results I am getting some errors

```
# Checking the output after filter
FILE_NAME = '2016-10-27.log.gz'
check_new_file = PROCESSED_LOG_PATH + FILE_NAME

new_entries = sc.textFile(check_new_file)
logs = new_entries.take(1)
  print (logs)
```

Error message:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 257.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 257.0 (TID 275, ip-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal): java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
```

I am guessing the problem is caused by the output format is saved back to S3. Is there a way to process and extract the lines I need from a log file, save the lines into another file to be stored on S3 and still work with the new stored file on S3 on Databricks?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, I think the problem is that your input file is gzip-compressed and decompression of that file was automatically handled by `sc.textFile`, but when you saved the file back to the `/processed` folder the new file was not compressed. Because the new file's name ends with `.gz`, Spark tries to decompress that file but the decompression fails.

To avoid this problem, consider either compressing the output that you write or rename the output file to omit the `.gz` extension.